# SPXPlatPluginsSuite->GetPluginXplatFileSpec returns XPlatFileSpec with mFileReference==0x00

Tags: photoshop-sdk

I am in the process of porting a legacy (CS5) Photoshop plugin for macOS written in C++ to current technology (Photoshop 2022, macOS 12.4).

I’m currently struggling with the fact that `CFURLCreateFromFSRef` is deprecated and should not be used any longer. Now, thanks to the newest version of the Plugins Suite, that shouldn’t be a problem, `SPXPlatPluginsSuite` should return an `XPlatFileSpec`, which gives the file location as a `CFURLRef`.

Unfortunately, if I acquire the suite with `kSPPluginsSuite` and `kSPPluginsSuiteVersion6`, then call `GetPluginXplatFileSpec`, the resulting `XPlatFileSpec.mFileReference` is `null`, the `mFileSpecVersion` is 0.

If I use `kSPPluginsSuiteVersion4` for the Suite acquisition, then call `GetPluginFileSpecification`, the resulting `SPPlatformFileSpecification.mReference` contains the correct (but useless) `FSRef`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it:

Stick with `kSPPluginsSuiteVersion4` and `GetPluginFileSpecification`, then use `PSGetPathSuite1` to get the path out of the returned `SPPlatformFileSpecification` as a string. From there I can create the URL as needed.